# Why process is not defined in web component?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, web-component

I've used Vue3 for building web component, and my Vue app is accessible through the following link:
[vue-app](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/amirtbi/vue-webcomponent/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000h2v6k7gaotu9m%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cll68ajhg026v2v6kzzoawdbo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000b2v6k0y58lmu0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll68a1a201p92v6k56b6345h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.vue%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll68ajhg026v2v6kzzoawdbo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cll689dl000xt2v6kz62u22p1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll689dl000xt2v6kz62u22p1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cll689anb00jw2v6k0nd911ux%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000f2v6kif7dz18o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cll6899230004d8i33k6i8xxk%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll689anb00jw2v6k0nd911ux%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

After running the `npm run build`, I've used the built files in a simple index.html. and wirte the following scripts inside of index.html:

```
<body>
<coin-tracker></coin-tracker>
    <script type='module'>
     import {register} from "./dist/index.js;
     register();

   </script>
</body>
```

But, when opening the html file, the following error appears:

> caught ReferenceError: process is not defined
> at shared.esm-bundler.js:10:19
> (

how can solve this issue?

Comment: The error you're encountering, "ReferenceError: process is not defined," is likely due to the fact that your Vue 3 application code is being bundled using the Vue CLI's default configuration, which assumes that it is running in a Node.js environment. However, when you're trying to use the bundled code in a browser environment, the process object is not available, leading to this error. Can you look at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#usebuiltins-usage.

Comment: I've used Vite as build tool.